# Using python import in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

[image]

I'm working with a Jupyter notebook. I'm trying to import

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # This is your Project Root
```

I'm getting a 'no module named main error'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming your `Untitled.ipynb` is in the notebooks directory, a quick hack is adding the parent directory into the path by `import sys; sys.path.append('../')` before trying to import

Comment: Would `%load main.py` be any use instead of an import?